# Basic Password Reset steps not working

Tags: users

I have reviewed other similar posts, but none matches my problem.

I built a Drupal site based on an old ASP.NET site. I imported the users from the old DB (which had passwords in plain text!). Most users have been able to log in fine, using their old username (email addresses) and passwords.

But a few users are having trouble logging in. In some cases they forgot their password from the old site.

So they request a new password on the login page, get the email with the one-time login link, use it to change their password, but they can't login again using the new password.

### What I have done to test / fix

- tried resetting password myself in a testing account I set up a couple months ago:

  - got reset password email link
  - made sure I was logged out on the site
  - user emailed link  to get into the account
  - entered new password
  - logged out and then couldn't log in again with the password I just entered ("`Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?`")
- tried using a different browser, flushed cookies and cache, all to no avail. I cannot seem to login to this account EXCEPT by requesting a password reset email and using the link in that. But if I log out, I cannot log in again.
- installed Password Reset Landing Page (https://www.drupal.org/project/prlp). This moved the password resetting to the page you land on from the email link, but it didn't solve the problem.
- I also just tried making a different **brand new testing account**, asking for a password reset, resetting as before. **This time it worked**. No idea why it works with this new account but not with the other, older testing account. To be clear, the old testing account *still* doesn't work following the same steps that worked for the **new** account.
- I monitored the user table in the DB. The password is being changed, but system doesn't recognize the newly entered password.

Is there anything I can post here to get help investigating this?

Comment: Any errors at `admin/reports/dblog` when you try any of the steps?

Comment: No, @Darvanen, there were no errors in the log.

Just: 
 - Password Reset Instructions
 - User XXXXX used one-time login link
 - Session opened for XXXXX
 - Session closed for XXXXX
 - Login attempt failed for XXXXX

All, as expected.

Comment: Any specifics on core and module versions or custom modules that tamper with user saving that you could tell us?

Comment: Sure. I am using the following modules.
User (core): 7.34,
User Import: 7.x-2.2, 
Profile2: 7.x-1.3, 
Profile2 Registration Path: 7.x-1.12

Comment: And there are three types of memberships (organized as Drupal Roles). The default registration assigns the user to one of the membership types.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce this but wasn't able to make it. Below is my process.

**no prlp module**

1. created new user with notify email
2. used onetime login link
3. changed password
4. logged out
5. logged in using the new password. *SUCCESS*

**with prlp module**

1. request new password
2. used onetime login link
3. changed password in the one time login page. *SUCCESS*
4. logged out
5. logged in using the new password

   5.1. using username 'asd'. *SUCCESS*

   5.2. using email 'asd@asd.com'. *FAIL (not relevant)*

**enabled logintoboggan (to use email as login)**

1. login using email and new password. *SUCCESS*
2. logout
3. request new password
4. used one time login link
5. changed password in the one time login page. *SUCCESS*
6. logged out
7. logged in using the new password

   7.1. using username 'asd'. *SUCCESS*

   7.2. using email 'asd@asd.com'. *SUCCESS*

Anything you'd like to add or to test?

Comment: Thank you! Your FAIL at your '5.2' with prlp testing brings up something I didn't mention earlier:

The old version of the site used email addresses as usernames. Since I was updating the site to Drupal (from an ASP.NET site, btw) and wanted to allow all the users of the old site to keep their same login info, I **KEPT** the email addresses as usernames. Is this a common cause of problems? I did an import of the users using User Import. The users with problems are part of this, but my test user was not imported this way and **does** use an email address as a username.

Comment: Have you installed logintoboggan and enable the use of email address to login in its configuration page?

Comment: No, I'm not using Logintoboggan (though I have on other sites). I just am using the legacy system of using email addresses both as usernames and email addresses in the user accounts. Is there some reason I should use Logintoboggan? as a test?

Comment: Oh yeah my bad! I was using a normal username not an email address. You don't need that module. I've tested again using a username with an email format but it's still working. O_O

Comment: Did you try creating a new user and try to do a reset password?

Comment: Yes, I did try this and that **new** test user account **did** work with the password reset. And I used an email address with that user as well, to try to duplicate everything. I'm not sure of this, but I think the only thing that is different between the new test user and the old one is when the new test user was created (i.e. yesterday instead of about a month ago).

Comment: That's really odd. Maybe it's just user error because as you said, other users has no issues and the data that you've checked are all in order right?